# remove prompt info from "write" command in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am using write command to work with CLI using the [SSHLibrary](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html), all prompt lines represented but the prompt remains as the last item. How can I erase this?

I used `Read Until Prompt` Keyword but I could not succeed. My code is as follows:

```
set client configuration  prompt=xx@edge-aa:~$
write  kubectl get svc --all-namespaces |awk 'NR>1 {print $2}'

sleep  10s

${output_get_svc}=  read until prompt
should end with  ${output_get_svc}  xxx@edge-aa:~$

sleep  2s

@{get_svc}=   split to lines  ${output_get_svc}
log to console  ${get_svc}
```

also, I added

```
open connection  ${ip_address}  port=${port}    prompt=xxx@edge-aa:~$   timeout=30s
```

Comment: Are you getting _only_ the prompt item, or are all prompt lines represented and the prompt is the last one?

Comment: all prompt lines represented and the prompt is the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation for the SSHLibrary keyword `Read Until Prompt` the [documentation](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html#Read%20Until%20Prompt) states:

> If you want to exclude the prompt from the returned output, set
>   strip_prompt to a true value

This suggests that when you change your line of code to:

```
${output_get_svc}=  Read Until Prompt  strip_prompt=True
```

It should result in what you want.